# twitter load home_timeline of user using streams?

Tags: node.js, twitter, stream

Im trying to create simple web that loads the timeline of a twitter user with this code:

```js
var params = {count:5, screen_name:"
              twitterUserScreenName"};
        client.get('statuses/home_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response){
          if (!error) {

            console.log("@" + tweets[0].user.screen_name + ":\n " +
                        tweets[0].text + " " 
              );

              //uncomment to see all the info of the tweet
            //console.log(tweets); 


          }
        });
```

Im using nodejs with this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter

My Question: to keep the timeline refresh I have to run the above code every interval of time, for example every 5 secs or every 20 secs, so Is there any way with streams to have the timeline of an user, i dont have to do several calls? do several calls to twitter server may place my app to a blacklist see [here more info](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting)

Answer (score -1):

ok, I solve it!

The thing is to use this function:

```js
client.stream('user', {},  function(stream) {

  stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
    console.log("----" + tweet.text);
  });

  stream.on('error', function(error) {
    throw error;
  });


});
```

with the above function u can show by console every tweet

Remember: Im using nodejs with this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter